# Unable to build static library during ndk build

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

We wanted to build a static library as part of ndk-build, but we are unable to do so when we have the APP_STL as c++_shared. Whereas, we are able to build the static library having it as c++_static.

Also we have noticed this pattern when we have a cpp file as part of src.

Can you please help us build a static library setting the APP_STL as c++_shared.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ndk-build only builds static libraries if they are needed or if there are only static libraries defined by the build. Since you have chose libc++_shared, there is a shared library defined by the build.

If you are building only a static library, switch to libc++_static. It makes no difference when building a static library since there is no link step for static libraries.

If you have other modules to build (shared libraries or executables), use the `APP_MODULES` variable to specify that the static libraries need to be built even though they are not depended upon.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk